# Mandar JSON de cliente a servidor FLASK

Tags: javascript, python, flask

mi pregunta es sencilla. ¿Cómo puedo generar un JSON y mandarlo al servidor para su posterior tratamiento? La única forma que tengo es recoger la información de los formularios HTML mediante un *request.form[x]*, pero supongo que habrá alguna forma de generar un JSON. Dejo a continuación el código:

Servidor:

```
@app.route('/homepage', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    #Compruebo el método
    if request.method == 'GET': 
        name = request.json['name']
        user = mongo.db.users.find_one({'name': name})
        response = json_util.dumps(user)
        print(response)
        return response
```

Cliente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <form class="" action="{{ url_for('homepage') }}" method="GET">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Sign in</h1>
        <input type=text id="name" placeholder="Name">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Como se ve, mi intención es recoger la información mediante *request.json[x]*, pero no conozco la forma de generar este JSON.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

cuando haces response.json, recoges el mensaje completo del request. Problema que la respuesta cuando la pasas al json, en ella tienes el contenido, headers, cookies... Yo te aconsejo que recojas el contenido que se encuentra en el text o en el content y pasarlo a json.

```
content_json = json.loads(request.text)
```

Con esta línea puedes recoger el response que se encuentra en el text y pasarlo a JSON. Y de ahí ya generas el JSON que desees.

Espero te sirva, un saludo.